# How can I do web hosting having all the code of the site stored on an SD?

Tags: sd-card, web-server

I am carrying out this project in which the Arduino acts as a web server and hosts a website in which I show the constantly updated temperature of a laboratory.

The problem is running all this code in the Arduino: memory runs out easily.

```cpp
void loop() {
  int value = analogRead(PIN_LM35);
  float temperature = value / 2.046;
  myFile = SD.open("temperature.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println(temperature);
  }
  myFile.close();

  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        //read char by char HTTP request
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          //store characters to string
          readString += c;
          //Serial.print(c);
        }

        //if HTTP request has ended
        if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.println(readString); //print to serial monitor for debuging

          client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")); //send new page
          client.println(F("Content-Type: text/html"));
          client.println();
          refreshcounter = refreshcounter + 1;
          client.println(F("<HTML>"));
          client.println(F("<HEAD>"));
          client.print(F("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2\">"));
          client.println(F("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />"));
          client.println(F("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black-translucent' />"));
          client.println(F("<TITLE>TEMPERATURE SENSOR LAB01</TITLE>"));
          client.println(F("</HEAD>"));
          client.println(F("<BODY>"));
          client.println(F("<H1>TEMPERATURE SENSOR LAB01</H1>"));
          client.println(F("<hr />"));
          client.println(F("<br />"));
          client.println(F("<H2>Arduino with Ethernet Shield</H2>"));
          client.println(F("<br />"));
          if (temperature < 24) {
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:50px; color:#8eff59; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;\">");
            client.println(temperature);
            client.println("</p>");
          }
          else if (temperature >= 24 && temperature <= 26) {
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:50px; color:#ffbc03; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;\">");
            client.println(temperature);
            client.println("</p>");
          }
          else {
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:50px; color:#ff0303; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;\">");
            client.println(temperature);
            client.println(F("<H2>It is recommended to activate the air conditioner.</H2>"));
            client.println("</p>");
          }
          client.println(F("<p style=\"font-size:30px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; ;\">Date/Time: <span id=\"datetime\"></span></p>"));
          client.println(F("<script>"));
          client.println(F("var dt = new Date();"));
          client.println(F("document.getElementById(\"datetime\").innerHTML = "
                "((\"0\"+dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) +\".\"+ ((\"0\"+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)) "
                "+\".\"+ (dt.getFullYear()) +\" \"+ ((\"0\"+dt.getHours()).slice(-2)) +\":\"+ ((\"0\"+dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2));"));
          client.println(F("</script>"));

          client.println("<svg width=\"1000\" height=\"250\">");
          client.println("<rect width=\"150\" height=\"5\" fill=\"gray\">");
          client.println("<animate attributeName=\"x\" from = \"0\" to =\"10000\" dur=\"10s\" fill=\"freeze\" />");
          client.println("</rect");
          client.println("</svg>");

          client.println("<br />");
          client.println("</BODY>");
          client.println("</HTML>");

          delay(1);
          //stopping client
          client.stop();
          //clearing string for next read
          readString = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I put all the code of the web page on an external SD card to save memory. However, I don’t really know how to use it from the SD card.

The problem that stops me is the fact that the site is not static, but is constantly updated with new temperature data.

How can I do that?

Comment: why you don't use F() for every string? With Arduino Uno if you use the Ethernet library and the SD library you run out of flash and SRAM very fast.

Comment: I tried, but I was running out of flash memory, too

Comment: You may want to detail what library, shield, and board you are using. Is this one of the standard AVR Arduinos? What hardware and library does it have that lets you run it as a server in the first place?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the wifi/ethernet shield library examples or the SD card library examples. You might find one that already does what you need. At very worst you can write a loop that reads characters or lines from the card and server.prints them. Make two files on the card that abut the print line to insert the temperature value, then print File 1, Temperature, File 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

> the site does not have to be static but constantly updated with new
> temperature data.

A good option is to use Ajax.
The basic idea is to split the site in two parts:

- a static part, potentially large, which contains all the user
  interface, the styling, the bells and whistles...
- a tiny, dynamic part that contains the data that is constantly updated
  *and nothing more*.

The static part would be served from the SD card when the client sends a
`GET /` request. The dynamic part would be served from another endpoint,
for example as a reply to `GET /temperature`. Serving the dynamic part
should be very simple, something like:

```cpp
client.println(temperature);
```

Yes, just send the number as ASCII, no HTML formatting. If you ever need
to send more than one number (e.g. multiple temperatures, or temperature
and humidity), format them in [JSON](https://www.json.org/). No need to use a library for
that, plain `print()` should be cheaper and good enough:

```cpp
client.print(F("{\"temperature\":"));
client.print(temperature);
client.print(F(",\"humidity\":"));
client.print(humidity);
client.print('}');
```

On the client side, `JSON.parse()` gets the data back as an easy-to-use
data structure.

Here is a minimal example of what the static part could look like.
Notice the JavaScript code sent to the client. This code is responsible
for querying the temperature every 1000 milliseconds, and updating the
Web page with the new data;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ajax test</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Ajax test</h1>

<p>Temperature: <span id="temperature">---</span> °C</p>

<script>
var data_field = document.getElementById("temperature");
setInterval(function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState != 4) return;
        data_field.innerText = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    };
    request.open("GET", "/temperature");
    request.send();
}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A few notes:

- This example is purposefully minimal. You may want to add some error
  checking, some decorations, some CSS and the such. Handling a
  temperature-dependent color also belongs to the client code.
- The example uses good old `XMLHttpRequest`. You may want to try the
  more modern [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead:

  ```js
  setInterval(function() {
      fetch("/temperature")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => { data_field.innerText = data; });
  }, 1000);
  ```
- If you are sending updates frequently enough to significantly load
  your Arduino, you may want to look at [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). This
  is a technique that allows you to significantly reduce the overhead of
  sending data updates. It is not as popular as Web-sockets, but has the
  advantage of being simpler to implement server-side.
- If you can put a reverse-proxy between your Arduino and the Internet,
  the proxy can handle the static content. Your Arduino then only
  handles the dynamic data and wouldn't need an SD card. If you
  reverse-proxy Server-sent events, make sure the proxy doesn't buffer
  the server response. See for example these [tips on configuring
  Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx) for this purpose.
- The static data could also be served from a completely different Web
  site. For this to work, you have to fulfill two conditions:

  1. The Arduino server has to add the header
     `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to its responses.
  2. On the client code, you have to provide the full URL of the Arduino
     as an argument of `request.open()`, `fetch()` or
     `new EventSource()`.
- The previous trick also allows you to open the Web page directly from
  your local file system, which can be very handy for developing.
- Once you get the basic scheme working, Web technologies allow you to
  get as fancy as you want. You could create an analogue gauge (with SVG
  transform rotate). You could even [add a graph](https://plotly.com/javascript/), updated in
  real time, that shows the time evolution of the temperature, and is
  entirely handled by the client.